# Property of solution to first order linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**The question**

Let $h:[0,\infty[\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $k:[0,\infty[\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous functions. We consider the ODE :$$y'(t)=h(t)+k(t)y(t)$$
for $t\geq 0$ with $y(t_0)=y_0$ as initial condition.

We suppose $h$ is a bounded function and that there exists $m>0$ such that $k(t)\geq m$, $\forall t\in[0,\infty[$. Show that, for $t_0=0$, there exists a unique $y_0$ for which the solution $y$ to the system is bounded.

**My thoughts**

I know that the solution to this system (once we take $t_0=0$) will be of the form
$$y(t)=e^{\int_0^t k(s)ds}\left(\int_{0}^te^{-\int_0^r k(s)dr}h(s)ds+y_0\right)$$

If I have existence of such a $y_0$, I know how to prove its uniqueness from properties proved in another part of the question. I was also able to prove in another part of the question that if we take $k(t)\leq -m$, then the solution is always bounded, whatever the $y_0$. But I was not able to adapt my proof in this case. I have tried many different manipulations but am always without success.

Can anyone tell me what I should do, or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the existence of $y_0$.  Let $K(t)=\int_0^tk(s)ds$, and choose $y_0=-\int_0^\infty e^{-K(s)}h(s)ds$.  We have $-K(t)\le -mt$, so $e^{-K(s)}\le e^{-ms}$, and $y_0$ exists. Now, $y(t)=-e^{K(t)}\int_t^\infty e^{-K(s)}h(s)ds.$  If $|h(t)|\le H$, then
$$
|y(t)|\le He^{K(t)}\int_t^\infty e^{-K(s)}ds,
$$
so it suffices to show the right hand side is bounded.  We have
$$
K(s)=K(t)+\int_t^sk(r)dr\ge K(t)+m(s-t),
$$
so
$$
|y(t)|\le H e^{mt}\int_t^\infty e^{-ms}ds=\frac{H}{m}.
$$

Comment: Wow! Very clear answer! Thank you very much, I do understand this problem much better now.

Comment: @tjeremie Happy to help!