# First order linear differential equation has unique bounded solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y'(x)=a(x)y(x)+b(x), x\in [0, +\infty)$, where $a,b$ are continuous functions over $[0,+\infty)$ and $b(x)$ is bounded, then show that:

1. If $a(x) \le m<0, \forall x \in [0,+\infty),$ then every solution of the differential equation is bounded.
2. If $a(x) \ge k>0, \forall x \in [0,+\infty),$ then there exists a unique solution that is bounded.

I think I have solved the first part correctly, however I am struggling with the second part. I found a similar question here: [Property of solution to first order linear ordinary differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465174/property-of-solution-to-first-order-linear-ordinary-differential-equation), but I don't understand how one derives that solution (if anyone can help me understand how to think to choose such a $y_0$) and also how to prove that it's unique. My progress so far starting from the first part: Solving for $y$ and integrating from $0$ to $x$ we get: $$y(x)=e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds}(\int_{0}^{x}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}dt+y(0))=\int_{0}^{x}b(t)e^{\int_{t}^{x}a(s)ds}dt+y(0)e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds}$$
and since $a(x) \le m$ and $|b(x)| \le M$, then $$|y(x)|=|\int_{0}^{x}b(t)e^{\int_{t}^{x}a(s)ds}dt+y(0)e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds}| \le |\int_{0}^{x}b(t)e^{\int_{t}^{x}a(s)ds}dt|+|y(0)|e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds} \le \\ \int_{0}^{x}|b(t)|e^{\int_{t}^{x}a(s)ds}dt+|y(0)|e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds} \le M\int_{0}^{x}e^{\int_{t}^{x}mds}dt+|y(0)|e^{\int_{0}^{x}mds}= \\ -\frac{M}{m}+\frac{M}{m}e^{mx}+|y(0)|e^{mx}<|y(0)|$$
since $m<0 \implies e^{mx}<1$ and so $y(x)$ is always bounded. Now for the second part I used the fact that $a(x)>k \iff -a(x)<-k$, I arrived similarly to this inequality:
$$|y(x)| \le \int_{0}^{x}|b(t)|e^{\int_{t}^{x}a(s)ds}dt+|y(0)|e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds}=\int_{0}^{x}|b(t)|e^{-\int_{x}^{t}a(s)ds}dt+|y(0)|e^{-\int_{x}^{0}a(s)ds} \le \\ M\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\int_{x}^{t}kds}dt+|y(0)|e^{-\int_{x}^{0}kds} = (\frac{M}{k}+|y(0)|)e^{kx}-\frac{M}{k}$$
which tends to $+\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$ and I am stuck here. Did I approach this part in a wrong way? For the uniqueness part my thought is that I need to somehow involve $y(0)$ in such an expression like above and probably for a single value of $y(0)$ we obtain an upper bound and since for each initial value problem the solution is unique, we are done. I'll be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know, from above, that the solution is: $$y(x)=e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds}\left(\int_{0}^{x}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}dt+y(0)\right)$$
and it is also easy to see that (from the triangle inequality and integration):
$\left |\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{x}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}dt}\right | \leq \frac{M}{k}(1-e^{-kx})$ and so we have that: $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\infty}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}}dt < +\infty$, since $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to +\infty}} \left(\frac{M}{k}(1-e^{-kx}) \right) = \frac{M}{k}$. In addition to that we also know, by integrating, that: $a(x)>k \implies e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds}> e^{kx} \implies \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to +\infty}} e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds} = +\infty$, since $k>0 \implies \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to +\infty}} e^{kx} = +\infty$. From these facts we have that:
$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to +\infty}} y(x) = (+\infty) \cdot \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}dt+y(0) \right) = \pm \infty$$ except when $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\infty}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}dt}+y(0) = 0$, and so $y(x)$ is unbounded in every other case. Now if $y(0) = \displaystyle{\int_{\infty}^{0}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}dt}$, then $$\boxed{y(x) = e^{\int_{0}^{x}a(s)ds} \displaystyle{\int_{\infty}^{x}}b(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}a(s)ds}dt = -\displaystyle{\int_{x}^{\infty}}b(t)e^{\int_{t}^{x}a(s)ds}dt}$$ now it only remains to show that this solution is bounded and we will have proven that it is the only bounded solution: $$|y(x)|\leq \left |\displaystyle{\int_{x}^{\infty}} b(t)e^{-\int_{x}^{t}a(s)ds}dt \right | \leq \displaystyle{\int_{x}^{\infty}} |b(t)|e^{-\int_{x}^{t}a(s)ds}dt \leq \displaystyle{\int_{x}^{\infty}} Me^{k(x-t)}dt = \frac{M}{k}$$
Q.E.D.